# Javascript: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <h1>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

EDITING to include solution based on Brian Hedlund's suggestion. Solution is at bottom.

I am getting this error in the console log

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: &lt;h1&gt;
```

This is the line generating the error

```
var substring = txt.find(tag).eq(i).text();
```

Sample data and code are below.

Why does that line throw that error and how can it be fixed?

I have verified that the function *_mpactIdeation_countOccurrences()* does execute properly as well as all lines in the function *mpactIdeation_getTagContentsKeyphrase()* above the line

```
var substring = txt.find(tag).eq(i).text();
```

Thanks for your time and consideration,
Tim

**Sample Data:**

The variable ***tag*** holds "<h1>".

The variable ***kp*** holds "fish".

The variable ***txt*** holds "<p>one.</p><h1>fish</h1><p>two fish. red fish. blue fish.</p>".

**Code:**

```
this.mpactIdeation_getTagContentsKeyphrase = function( tag, kp ) {
        try {
            var result = 0;
            var num = 0;
            var txt = this.oText;

            var tagcount = this._mpactIdeation_countOccurrences( txt, tag, false );

            txt = jQuery(txt);

            for (i = 0; i < tagcount; i++) {
                tag = this._mpactIdeation_escapeRegExp(tag);
                var substring = txt.find(tag).eq(i).text();
                result += this._mpactIdeation_countOccurrences(substring, kp, false);
            }

            return num;
        }  catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    this._mpactIdeation_countOccurrences = function( string, subString, allowOverlapping ) {
        try {
            string += "";
            subString += "";

            if (subString.length <= 0) return (string.length + 1);

            var num = 0,
                pos = 0,
                step = allowOverlapping ? 1 : subString.length;

            while (true) {
                pos = string.indexOf(subString, pos);
                if (pos >= 0) {
                    ++num;
                    pos += step;
                } else break;
            }
            return num;
        }  catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

SOLUTION:

```
this.mpactIdeation_getTagContentsKeyphrase = function( tag, kp ) {
    try {
        var result = 0;
        var num = 0;
        var txt = this.oText;

        var tagcount = this._mpactIdeation_countOccurrences( txt, tag, false );

        txt = jQuery(txt);
        tag = this._mpactIdeation_tagToText(tag);

        for (i = 0; i < tagcount; i++) {
            var substring = txt.find(tag).eq(i).text();
            result += this._mpactIdeation_countOccurrences(substring, kp, false);
        }

        return num;
    }  catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        return false;
    }
}

this._mpactIdeation_countOccurrences = function( string, subString, allowOverlapping ) {
    try {
        string += "";
        subString += "";

        if (subString.length <= 0) return (string.length + 1);

        var num = 0,
            pos = 0,
            step = allowOverlapping ? 1 : subString.length;

        while (true) {
            pos = string.indexOf(subString, pos);
            if (pos >= 0) {
                ++num;
                console.log( "countOccurrences FOUND: " + subString + " INCREMENT");
                pos += step;
            } else break;
        }
        return num;
    }  catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        return false;
    }
}

this._mpactIdeation_tagToText = function(tag) {
    try {
        return tag = tag.replace(/[<>]/g, '');
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct `find` syntax is `find('h1')`, not `find('<h1>')`

This will fix your error, but not find your h1. `find` looks for descendants of the searched target, and since your `txt` has no root node, the intended target `h1` is not a descendant, but a sibling. `.siblings('h1')` would do the trick.

Comment: Got it! I need to strip the angle brackets before that line. I'll go test that. Be right back. Thanks

Comment: @mpactMEDIA: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ lists all selectors you can use with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks @David Hedlund. I've edited my question to include a solution based on your input. Greatly appreciated. This did raise another Question. I'll post it separately.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks. Helpful.